# How to call .Net Core classes from Java on Docker

Tags: java, docker, .net-core, containers, ikvm

We have a bunch of .Net classes which we need to call in Docker containers now. Our guys maintaining the containers say that the containers are linux and that windows containers are not supported yet. The 3rd party product calling our .net code can call only java code on containers. So we cannot use .net core directly on the containers. We'll either rewrite the entire code in Java or just write Java stubs and call our .net code from those stubs..

I inspected IKVM and jni4net, but they don't seem to help. IKVM seems to use a specific VM (which I don't know if supported on docker) and jni4net requires Windows runtime.

What other free/open source options do we have?

Comment: Would it be possible to split your existing codebase to minimal Linux-like utilities? 
E.g. you have a massive library with lots of different functions. Instead of that, create a multitude of smaller applications which you could then call directly?

These can then easily be called from Java and you wouldn't have to re-write the entire code base.

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding your question, but maybe expose the .NET classes via API(s)? Then call the :NET API(s) from your Java app(s) via http/gRPC?

Comment: @Henkolicious I've skimmed through gRPC documentation and I gues we'll have to write proto files for each public method of each public class in our .net class library. This will mean hundreds of proto files, which will look as difficult as rewriting the entire class library in Java to my colleagues :) If I didn't get gRPC wrong, we'll have to write the Java stub I mentioned in my question as well. Not sure if this is the simplest solution.

Comment: @SimonC What kind of utilities in Linux, can you be more specific? Our current code is actually test automation code, which calls Selenium API; will these utilities call Selenium as well?

Comment: Instead of having one huge library, split the library in to many little applications is what I meant.

Comment: What is the .NET code expected to do? Do you have a chance to publish it externally, I mean outside your docker environment?

Comment: .Net code is test automation code: It uses selenium to instantiate a browser and make some UI tests on the Docker image.

Answer (score 0):

JNBridge works with .NET Core, and with Docker.

See https://jnbridge.com/ and https://jnbridge.com/blog/creating-microservices-docker-jnbridgepro (which uses Mono in the example, but should work equally well with .NET Core).

Comment: I guess due to JNBridge licencing, my management will decide to rewrite the class library entirely in Java, instead of depending on a 3rd party to avoid rewriting 3000 lines of code. What we're looking for is a free/open source solution.